# Multibit seed/ or files to Electrum wallet

Tags: electrum, multibit-hd

i tried moving multibit wallet as explained here but failed.  https://youtu.be/E-KcY6KUVnY i have the seed and password from Multibit wallet and some files from backup folder in the 'mbh......aes' format. Any help i'll appreciate 
 Am using linux

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified how it failed so we can only guess. [Here's](https://bitcoinelectrum.com/restoring-your-multibithd-wallet-in-electrum/) a more detailed guide. Pay attention to the last two paragraphs and try again.